# Sorting a dictionary to an OrderedDict with a single key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to write some code which creates a sorted `OrderedDict`. The code will have an unordered `dict` passed to it. Unfortunately, it seems that `OrderedDict(sorted(x))` explodes when the dictionary `x` only has one key:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> a = {"b": 1}
>>> OrderedDict(a)
OrderedDict([('b', 1)])
>>> sorted(a)
['b']
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(a))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/collections/__init__.py", line 56, in __init__
    self.__update(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/_collections_abc.py", line 602, in update
    for key, value in other:
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
>>>
```

Of course, I realise that I can just check the number of keys in the dictionary and behave appropriately. However, I wanted to check if I am doing something wrong here, because it seems like it should work. Is there a better/more appropriate way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initialiser for `dict`/`OrderedDict` objects requires an interable of pairs `key, val`.

As you clearly show in your testing, `sorted(a)` is an iterable but **not of pairs**, hence `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`.

If you want to create a dictionary from `sorted(a)`, you should do it `.fromkeys`:

```
>>> OrderedDict.fromkeys(sorted(a))
OrderedDict([('b', None)])
```

but I think you really want:

```
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(a.items()))
OrderedDict([('b', 1)])
```